# Deserialize JSON string into a List of POJOs

Tags: java, json, google-app-engine, jackson, google-cloud-endpoints

Here is my code for deserializing the response I get back from a Google App Engine Cloud Endpoint:

```
String jsonString = IOUtils.toString(
    httpResponse.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8");

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ArrayList<myPOJO> myList= 
    mapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<ArrayList<MyPOJO>>(){});
```

jsonString looks like this:

```
{
  "items" : [ {
    "id" : "12345",
    "name" : "test1"
  }, {
    "id" : "121212",
    "name" : "test2"
  } ]
}
```

But I am getting this error:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token at [Source: java.io.StringReader@547a7880; line: 1, column: 1]
```

What is the proper way to deserialize this JSON into a List of POJOs with Jackson?

Comment: Your jsonString is an object, not list.

Comment: You can use jackson library for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

try deserializing directly with the mapper

```
String jsonString = IOUtils.toString(
        httpResponse.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8");

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    List<MyPOJO> myList= mapper.convertValue(jsonString, mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, MyPOJO.class));
```

Comment: That doesn't work. the error just changes to `Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token
`

Answer (score 0):

You have to create root `POJO` for your `JSON` root object. For example:

```
class Root {

    private List<Entity> items;

    //getters, setters, toString, etc
}

class Entity {

    private long id;
    private String name;

    //getters, setters, toString, etc
}
```

Simple app:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Root list = mapper.readValue(json, Root.class);
System.out.println(list);
```

prints:

```
Root [items=[Entity [id=12345, name=test1], Entity [id=121212, name=test2]]]
```